# Service shouldn't unbind after rotation

Tags: android

I got a problem with my app. I'm using a service which binds to every activity when an activity starts.
So my problem is when the display rotates the current activity will be destroyed and new created. This causes my service to unbind from the current activity and a new service is created binded to the new activity. But this is what I want to avoid. The new activity created after the rotation should be bind to the current service.
Hope somebody can help me.

Regards,

Xoidberg

Comment: Thanks for checking out Android Enthusiasts. Please read the [FAQ](http://android.stackexchange.com/faq) since development questions are off topic for this site.

Comment: @Xoidberg Daniel's right.  Your question will likely be migrated to StackOverflow.com shortly.